# Issue with text on a photo and making it responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a web project in which I have a picture in the center of the screen. On top of that picture I have some text in a box. When the screen is full width I "almost" have it as large as I want. However, when I make the screen smaller the text moves all over the place.

**I have the following code:**

```css
.imageFit {
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.imageText span { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 75%;
  left: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="imageFit" src="https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1420593248178-d88870618ca0">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="imageText "><span>Begins with one step</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Hint:** Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: did you want the text to stay in the center of the image?

Comment: is this all of your code? do you have styles set with the selector .container ?

Comment: Yes, wanted it to stay in the very center of the image as the page changes. .container is a class from bootstrap, not in my CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it all css, you can take out the `<h1>` tags and just do `:before` selector with content:

https://jsfiddle.net/ukdt27oz/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="imageFit" src="https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1420593248178-d88870618ca0">
</div>

 .imageFit {
   padding-top: 5%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .container:before {
   content: "Begins with one step";
   color: black;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%;
   left: 35%;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align:center;
   color: white;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   letter-spacing: -1px;
   font-size: 5vw;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. I removed some unnecessary tags and also made your text responsive.

```css
.imageFit {
   padding-top: 5%;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .imageText { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   padding: 10px;
   text-align:center;
   color: white;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   letter-spacing: -1px;
   font-size: 4vw;
  }
.container {
  position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="imageFit" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/12/19/16/painting-1136443_960_720.jpg">
  <h1 class="imageText ">Begins with one step</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much it-text is not 100% centered or where I would like it but I can modify that! Thank you!

Comment: no problem  wait i center it for you there is an nifty trick for that XD

Answer (score 1):

It's always going to be tricky getting absolutely positioned elements to shift around the DOM in the way you expect.

`absolute` positioned elements are taken out of the natural document flow, they have no relation to other elements shifting around them.

We can control this to an extent by declaring `position: relative;` on a given parent element. This will now position it relative to this parent.

```css
.imageFit {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }

 .imageText span { 
   position: absolute; 
   left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-height: 65px;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align:center;
   color: white;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   letter-spacing: -1px;
  }

.container-wrapper {
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
        <img class="imageFit" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=75&txt=800%C3%97500&w=800&h=500">
        <div class="container">
           <h1 class="imageText "><span>Begins with one step</span></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```